# How do we get list of users within range of certain city?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I have list of users with field city. How do we get list of users who are about 200km from certain city?

I am using geocoder gem to find nearest location. However, how do we do it through city only without lat and lon present on the db for User?

```
user = User.last    
user.address = 'Sydney'
location = Geocoder.search(user.address).first
lat = location.latitude
lon = location.longitude

within_user = SpreeUser.near([lat, lon], 200, units: :km)
```

This will give the error because latitude and longitude does not exist for User. Is there a way it can be done through other field, like address in this case?

Comment: `Geocoder` does returns the `latitude` and `longitude` for given address. I am not sure if I understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

As the [geocoder docs](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#geocoding-objects) state, you can geocode your users easily.

In your model:

- Add columns `latitude` and `longitude` to your model.
- Tell geocoder how the method to geocode: `geocoded_by :address`
- Add the callback: `after_validation :geocode`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your question that you have already field named 'city' in User table.

(reference: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#geocoding-objects)

Try this:

```
SpreeUser.near('Austin', 200, units: :km)      # users within 200 kms of Austin city
```